# How to Display WP Blog Posts on views_embed_view in Drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal, blogs

Anyone can help me on how to display WP Blog Posts on a block in a page using views_embed_view in Drupal?

Answer (score -1):

You have to install feeds module and add your blog rss: https://drupal.org/project/feeds

Then you should configure a cron job to automatically execute imports: https://drupal.org/cron

Finally, you have to create a view and get all the new content to display. Also you can use views_embed_view if you want to display the view manually.

Regards.

Comment: hi Mario, I added my content from Drupal and it's type is WP blog post. Please let me know if it is not clear. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I thought that WP blog posts is an external data from some WP site.
You have to create a view and filter it by this content type, do you know views?

Comment: I'm beginner with Drupal, can you help me where can I create a view, is it under templates folder? and how to name and call that view? thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry. Maybe you should read a tutorial of drupal. There is a module named views here: https://drupal.org/project/views. You have to download here and upload it into sites/all/modules folder. The final result would be sites/all/modules/views.  Then you have yo enable the module in "Modules" section. I recommend you to read this article: http://www.acquia.com/blog/totally-beginner-tutorial-views-drupal-7